# How to implement a database like search form into a website?

Tags: php, html, database, search, web

How can I go about implementing a database like search form into an HTML website? For example, there is a form to enter your zip code and after entering the zip code, it searches a .txt file (for example) and returns results that fall under that specific zip code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: break it down. you need some code to enter the zip in. some code to send it to the server. some code to search the file or db. some code to return the results. some code to display the results

Comment: I would recommend MySQL over a text file

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches you could take.  It's a very broad question.

As an example solution, you would need to have both client and server side code.  The client would submit the form to a server.  The server code could be written in a multitude of languages, PHP, ASP, JAVA etc.

The server side code would take the request parameters sent by the form, read the file, calculate any result and pass it back in the http response to the front end, which could be dealt with by displaying a new page or as part of an AJAX refresh.

As you can appreciate though, this is a very broad topic and there are many possible solutions.

Also as @Dagon points out, if you are not restricted to using a text file (although your title probably suggests you are) then using a MySQL or other such database could be a better solution, maybe even Solr as an indexing solution, depending on what you are searching for.